# Rendered partial not receiving params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, routes, partial-views

I'm trying to implement an 'edit' link that brings up a form to change a displayed attribute on a page.

My layout has:

```
<div id="company_info">
  <%= yield :company_info %>
</div>
<div id="edit_company_info">
</div>
```

My view has:

```
<%= content_for :company_info do %>
<%= render 'company_info' %>
<%= link_to "Edit", 'company_info_form', :class => 'btn btn-mini', :method => :get, :remote => true %>
```

My controller has:

```
 def company_info_form
   @company = Company.get(params[:id])

   respond_to do |format|
      format.js
   end
 end
```

My company_info_form.js.erb file has:

```
$('#edit_company_info').html("<%= escape_javascript(render "company_info_form") %>");
```

Upon clicking the link, my server shows:

```
Started GET "/companies/company_info_form" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-12 20:19:13 -0700
Processing by CompaniesController#show as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"company_info_form"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

RuntimeError (Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id):
app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:9:in `show'
```

So I think this is a routing issue-- but I have no idea how to fix it.  How do I get the company_id param that is on my current page to be recognized by the partial I'm loading as well?

I'm on `/companies/1`, but the link is to `companies/company_info_form`, losing the `"company_id = 1"` param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the issue is with your routes and with your link as you have pointed out.

The first issue can be ascertained  as it says `Processing by CompaniesController#show as JS`. So, its actually going to `companies#show` where it tries to find a company based on id. But, since no correct `id` is passed, it errors out.

The second issue is because your link is to `companies/company_info_form`, as you pointed out, since you have used `'company_info_form'` as the path in your link for edit. And you haven't passed current company to the link either.

Since you haven't posted your routes file, which you should have, since you have identified a potential problem with routes , I'll present my own.

In your routes :

```
resources :companies do
  member do
    get 'company_info_form'
  end
end
```

That will provide you with

```
company_info_form_company GET    /companies/:id/company_info_form(.:format) companies#company_info_form
```

Then you can provide the link as :

```
<%= link_to "Edit", company_info_form_company_path(@company) %>
```